# wordpress replace text before showing it to the browser

Tags: wordpress

My website is built using `Elementor` using `GeneratePress` as default theme and I want to replace output final text with some values from the database. This plugin
`Real-Time Find and Replace` https://wordpress.org/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/ is doing the replace functionality perfectly and it uses action:

```
//Handles find and replace for public pages
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'far_template_redirect' );
```

to replace text using code:

```
function far_ob_call( $buffer ) { // $buffer contains entire page

    $far_settings = get_option( 'far_plugin_settings' );
    if ( is_array( $far_settings['farfind'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $far_settings['farfind'] as $key => $find ) {
            if( isset( $far_settings['farregex'][$key] ) ) {
                $buffer = preg_replace( $find, $far_settings['farreplace'][$key], $buffer );
            } else {            
                $buffer = str_replace( $find, $far_settings['farreplace'][$key], $buffer );
            }
        }
    }
    return $buffer;
}
```

I can not use the plugin directly because it repalce text with text and I need to fetch data from database, so I have to make my own plugin. But, I found this blog: https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/ that tells me to use a filter:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_callback' );
```

instead of the above action in plugin:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'far_template_redirect' );
```

But the plugin is using the action.

What to use?

The plugin description says: `"Set up find and replace rules that are executed AFTER a page is generated by WordPress, but BEFORE it is sent to a user's browser."` this is what I exactly want. That is to replace text after page is generated and just before the page is sent to browser, but the plugin uses `action` for this, and other blogs suggest to use `filter`?

Comment: I guess the second snippet of code you placed in your question it can do the work. Inside the callback, you could use the `$wpdb` and the `WP_Query` to form the database queries you need, and once you have the values from the DB, you could make your replacement.

Comment: but I want to know which is better to use? action or filter?

Comment: Use the filter. The purpose of filters is to modify data and return the modifications back. The actions are responsible to execute code in specific timeslots of the execution time.

Comment: can you answer my another question on same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748706/search-and-replace-text-in-wordpress-using-ob-start