# Search and replace text in Wordpress using ob_start

Tags: wordpress

I am doing text replace in WordPress using code sample from plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/

My code is:

```
<?php

function ss_ob_call( $buffer ) // $buffer contains entire page
{
    $buffer = str_replace("old_text", "new_text", $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}

function ss_template_redirect() {
    ob_start();
    ob_start( 'ss_ob_call' );
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'ss_template_redirect' );

?>
```

It works fine, but I want to know why the plugin creator has called `ob_start` twice?

And why

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'ss_ob_call' );
```

does not work but

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'ss_template_redirect' );
```

works fine?

I mean why do I need to call `ob_start` to execute the main function, and why direct function call is not working?

Comment: In PHP you could have nested `ob_start` calls. This means, that the first `ob_start` call buffers a broader output of the output produced by PHP, while the second `ob_start` will buffer a sub-part of the output. Think of it like, start buffering the whole output in the first call, while the second call buffers only a small part of the output for further processing. Now the reason it doesn't work the first `add_filter` statement it's not clear without the actual plugin source code. I guess you have to make a deepr look in the source code :)

Comment: I only wrote above code in new plugin. there is no other code except for what I pasted above. And I don't understand why direct function call doesn't work. But function call from ob_start works fine

Comment: Then you should read what the ob_start (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) does. Normally when you execute a php script _(In WordPress case a page)_ the output of the page is send directly to the browser. With ob_start, you could start a new short memory that holds the output of the PHP before this is sent to the browser, for further processing before you send it back to the browser. I am not really sure, but I think if you don't use the `ob_get_contents()` or `ob_flush`, the contents of the short memory you made is flushed anyway.